# Кодировка текста

Tags: кодировка, php, html

\000\000\000\000 - Подскажите , что за кодировка, а то знакомое что-то, а вспомнить немогу.

Comment: четыре символа с кодом 0? кодировка строк в каком-нибудь языке программирования (должно быть в js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да в html это utf просто кодами записан, вот сейчас не вспомню восмеричными или 16 ричными но тпо моету так: \0х000 шестнадцетироичный \000 восмеричный